# How do I make that difference from months using standardSQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT distinct  (grand_total/months) AS avg, ((grand_total/days)) AS 
avg_day
FROM 
(select count(searchint.id) as Total, (DATE_DIFF(DATE ({{DATE_END}}), 
DATE ({{DATE_START}}), DAY)+1) AS days, ((12 * YEAR(TIMESTAMP({{DATE_END}})) + 
MONTH(TIMESTAMP({{DATE_END}}))) - (12 * YEAR(TIMESTAMP({{DATE_START}})) 
+ MONTH(TIMESTAMP({{DATE_START}}))) +1) AS months,
(select count(searchint.id) as Total
from `dbsearch`
where  cast(replace(searchint.createdDate,'Z','')as DateTime) >= 
cast({{DATE_START}} as DateTime)
and  cast(replace(searchint.createdDate,'Z','')as DateTime) <= 
cast(DATE_ADD(cast({{DATE_END}} as date),  Interval 1 day ) as DateTime)) AS grand_total
    from `dbsearch`
where  cast(replace(searchint.createdDate,'Z','')as DateTime) >= 
cast({{DATE_START}} as DateTime)
and  cast(replace(searchint.createdDate,'Z','')as DateTime) <= 
cast(DATE_ADD(cast({{DATE_END}} as date),  Interval 1 day ) as DateTime)
group by date(cast(replace(searchint.createdDate,'Z','')as DateTime))
ORDER BY 2 DESC) AS groupby
```

However, when I try to run BigQuery it gives the following error:

Function not found: YEAR at [5:180]

I understand it's because I'm using standardSQL, but how do I make that difference from months using standardSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find difference in months between two dates you better to use [`DATE_DIFF()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff)

```
DATE_DIFF(DATE_END, DATE_START, MONTH)
```

Answer (score 2):

StandardSQL in BigQuery supports the ISO/ANSI-standard function for extracting date parts.  This is `extract()`:

You want:

```
extract(year from <datecol>)
extract(month from <datecol>)
```

This is explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators).